# Typo3: Redirect after login not working

Tags: typo3

This is T3 v6.2.36 and I have a login page with a subpage. The subpage is restricted to login users and hence does not appear in the menu before login. When I click on the login page in the menu and enter the credentials I do not get redirected to the subpage. I have set the redirect target page in the user group. Also I have set the login plugin to "redirect defined by user group". It sounds so easy and intuitive, yet it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh my god, how can people be so incapable. It's a translation error in the backend. In english the option of the CE in the backend is called "Disable redirect after successful login, but display logout-form". I had that box checked because in german it only says "Display logout form after succesful login". Can't believe it. Luckily my test install is in english (the one on the server is in german), that's how I found out. I would have never gotten to the solution if I had installed only the german version. What a poor job by the guy who translated this ...

Comment: The english label was improved later, the german label may still be the first version. It’s still an open source project, so you could be the awesome guy who improves this label for german users.

Comment: the install on the server (german) is version 6.2.36 (I think that is ELTS because you cannot download that version on sourceforge). How do I know where you can download 6.2.36 and change that download source code retrospectively?